# WPF Canvas inheritance, mouse events not detected

Tags: wpf, canvas, wpf-controls

I made a child class of Canvas WPF class to change rendering function.
However, when I try to change its background property in child class to handle mouse events properly
it is not working. When manually set background in xaml with Background="White" in editor it is not working.

Where am I wrong. Beside that I would prefer adding canvaschild dynamically instead of using editor.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify: you've written a custom panel derived from Canvas, and if you set its background in Xaml or in the child class to a color, it won't detect mouseover or mouse clicks?